# Installing All Packages in a PPA

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa

How do I download all of the packages contained within a particular PPA in one command, without explicitly listing out each package?

For example, say I want to download [all 108 or so packages contained within the Backbox PPA](https://launchpad.net/~backbox/+archive/three) *without* having to type out each package like this:

```
sudo apt-get install package1, package2, package3, package4, package5
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you don't. If the owner of the PPA has made a meta-package, which depends on all the other packages in the PPA, then you would be able to install that package and it will pull in everything else.

In the case of the Backbox PPA you mentioned, this has been done via the `backbox-meta` source package, which provides the `backbox-minimal`, `backbox-desktop`, and `backbox-server` meta packages, which depend on different sets of packages in that archive. Assuming it is updated, and all three packages depend on everything else in the PPA, you can run `sudo apt-get install backbox-minimal backbox-desktop backbox-server` to install everything.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure if you have found the answer, but here is what worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install backbox-tools
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I wanted to expand a little and give a quick step by step  
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y 
sudo apt-get install vim 
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list  

Add the following  
##Backbock tools installed (enter date here)              
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/backbox/four/ubuntu trusty main  
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/backbox/four/ubuntu trusty main 

sudo apt-get update  

sudo apt-get install backbox-tools  
This part will take a bit and you will have to acknowledge a thing or two

Answer (score 0):

The work has been done for you. Use one of the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install backbox-minimal
sudo apt-get install backbox-desktop
sudo apt-get install backbox-server
```

The `backbox-desktop` metapackage has all of the packages, while `backbox-minimal` will give you a functional command-line system.